# Child component does not re-render and never print console log

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm creating a table with child components named Header and Body. It seems to render fine, but when I change an input field and then a date in a next field, it wipes the value in the first input field, even tho the reducer displays correct in both of them. Also the onChange method that the input field has as a prop is being used, however the console log in the component never runs. Not when value is changed and not at first render at all. Nothing that I log inside that file is being printed, but if i change a placeholder its being changed. So im pretty sure im inside the correct location. Any thoughts?

Example of code

```
const MemberRow = ({
  intl: { formatMessage, locale }, member, companyId, updates, onBlur, onChange, onRemove, relocateMemberActions, ...rest
}) => {
  const [memberUpdate, setMemberUpdate] = useState(updates);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('updates child', updates, memberUpdate);
    if (updates !== memberUpdate) {
      setMemberUpdate(updates);
    }
  }, [updates, member, memberUpdate]);

  const handleOnChangeMember = (e) => {
    console.log('kommer vi hit', member)
    console.log(e)
    const { ssn } = member;
    const { target: { dataset: { attr }, value } } = e;
    relocateMemberActions.updateMember(ssn, { [attr]: value });
  };

return (
  <td>
          <Input
            aria-label={formatMessage(GeneralMessages.workPercent)}
            // status={(updates.errors && updates.errors.partTimePercentageShare
            //   && updates.errors.partTimePercentageShare[0])}
            placeholder={formatMessage(RelocateMessages.nameOrOrgNumber)}
            on_change={({ value }) => handleOnChangeMember({
              value,
              attr: 'organization',
            })}
            on_blur={onBlur}
            value={updates.organization || null}
          />
        </td>
)
};

const DesktopBody = ({
  members, updates, companyId, ...rest
}) => {
  console.log('desktopBody', companyId, rest);
  useEffect(() => {
  }, [members, updates, companyId, rest]);
  return (
    <tbody>
      {members.map(member => (
        <MemberRow key={member.ssn} {...rest} member={member} companyId={companyId} updates={updates[member.ssn] || {}} />
      ))}
    </tbody>
  );
};
```

There might look like syntax error since i cut some code off, but there is not. The code runs perfectly and is not breaking.

Comment: sample code would be really helpful to understand your issue, if you can please post the code

Comment: it's incomplete. there is a `onChange` prop in `MemberRow`, but you never assigned anything to it. if it's mapped to redux store, you should add that code as well. also `on_change` is not getting fired (since you can't see any loggs), but you didn't add the code for `Input` component as well. Ps. you forget to add the code for `date input` as well.

Comment: @RohitAmbre check now

Comment: @yaya DesktopBody is also a child from something else. The onChange is in the rest and it is updating the reducer with it. So its working and its being fired. Its also logging from the onChange in its parent.